# CMake `add_executable` and `target_link_libraries` throwing linking error

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, target-link-libraries

I am following [`Asio` tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UbjxGvrDrbw&t=1223s) by [`javidx9`](https://www.youtube.com/@javidx9) and using `CMake` to link my executables and libraries. Complete source code is available in [this repository](https://github.com/mjrusty/asio-web-trial).

I am facing a linking error with the executables `Server.cpp` and `Client.cpp` in folder

```
- Source
---- Main
-------- Server.cpp
-------- Client.cpp
```

In the `main` function if I create the class object `CustomServer` which inherits from `ServerInterface`

```
int main ()
{
    CustomServer server(60000);
    return 0;
}
```

I get following linking error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Tachys::Networking::ServerInterface<CustomMessageTypes>::ServerInterface(unsigned short)", referenced from:
      CustomServer::CustomServer(unsigned short) in Server.cpp.o
  "Tachys::Networking::ServerInterface<CustomMessageTypes>::~ServerInterface()", referenced from:
      CustomServer::~CustomServer() in Server.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [Source/Main/exe_server] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Source/Main/CMakeFiles/exe_server.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

But I have used `add_executable` in the `CMakeList.txt` at:

```
- Source
---- Main
-------- CMakeLists.txt
```

and `target_link_libraries` in the main `CMakeLists.txt` at:

```
- CMakeLists.txt
```

It seems like these are the only two functions required to create an executable and link it to a created library but I am still getting this linking error and not able to figure out what to change. Please help.

Comment: Please, add relevant **code** to the **question post** itself. It is a requirement of Stack Overflow, and neither a link to the guide nor a link to the repo fulfil that requirement. Preferably, the question post should contain a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have template `ServerInterface<CustomMessageTypes>` implemented in a source file. Either move the implementation to a header, which is usually what you do, or provide the symbol `ServerInterface<CustomMessageTypes>` by explicitly instantianting the template in source file. See [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) and other endless online resources.

> ```
> __Start__
> ```

Identifiers starting with double underscores are reserved. You are can't use them in your code.